# How can i make a JSlider modify a threads sleep time?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Currently making a GUI in Java swing that animates sorting algorithms and the paint method uses a Thread.sleep so i see it being painted. Wondering how i can add a slider that can change the Thread.sleep time increase or decrease.

Answer (score 1):

Share a value somehow (such as an `AtomicInteger`) between the class that listens to `JSlider` and the `Thread` object that sleeps.

Make sure you make the code thread safe as well so the proper latest value is seen by the thread that sleeps .

Comment: "thread safe as well?"  If the message to be communicated is a single int value, and if it's passed through an AtomicInteger instance, what could be any safer than that?

Comment: @jameslarge I wasn't saying specifically to use AtomicInteger, it was a suggestion of a possible means, so the comment to keep it threadsafe was a reminder to do so in any solution used, AtomicInteger or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) to have some example about using a JSlider. You just have to get the changed value and modify your sleep time by this value.. By a simple variable.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this is possible. You can try doing this, but I am not sure that it will work:

```
int a;
Thread.sleep(a);
```

If this does not give any error, then you can work with this.